# EFCore.BulkExtensions with postgresql provider generates table and column names in capital letters

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql, efcore.bulkextensions

I'm using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` 6.0 and `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` 6.0.
I have a dbContext that is configured like this:

```cs
var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataProtectionDbContext>();
dbContextOptions.UseNpgsql(config.GetConnectionString("DataProtection"), x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable(Constants.EFCoreMigrationsHistoryTableName))
                    .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();
```

I have a bound property in the context that I use `.BatchDelete()` on.

```cs
var query = dataProtectionDbContext.Temporarys.Where(m => m.CreatedTime < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-temporarys_MaxAgeInDays));
query.BatchDelete();
```

The problem is, that I got an error logged in the console `Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P01: relation "TEMPORARYS" does not exist`
The generated sql is:

```sql
DELETE
FROM "TEMPORARYS" AS t
WHERE t."CREATED_TIME" < (now() + CAST((@__p_0::text || ' days') AS interval))
```

The problem is, that the table name and the column name are configured to be in lowercase:

```cs
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "temporarys",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                    created_time = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                    tenant_id = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 50, nullable: true),
                    key = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 50, nullable: true),
                    value = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Temporarys", x => x.id);
               });
```

Can someone help me, how can I do this to work and not convert the table and column names?
Or is there some special configuration that I have to make in order this to work with PostgreSQL?

Best Regards,

Julian

Comment: Note that EF Core 7.0 introduced [ExecuteDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates) as a built-in alternative to at least some of the functionality EFCore.BulkExtensions. It shouldn't have the issue above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Shay Rojansky suggested in the comment section, upgrading to EF Core 7.0 does the trick